# Changing pushViewController's "animated:" Flag Changes SpriteKit Resolution

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, sprite-kit

I have a subclassed `UINavigationController` that navigates through a series of view controllers by calling `[self pushViewController:controller animated:YES]`.

Each of these view controllers contains an SKScene.

The transition between view controllers looks bad, so I decided to change it by switching the animated flag to `NO`, i.e. `[self pushViewController:controller animated:NO]`. However, when I change this flag from YES to NO, my SKScene doubles in size. It's as if it thinks that I'm changing the retina/@2x properties or something.

Why does the animation flag affect SKScene frame size? And how would I transition between view controllers without an animation?

Comment: you are not supposed to do that, instead transition between scenes not views and their controllers. It's inefficient to recreate sk views for every "transition".

Comment: In general, I agree. However, the issue here is that my `SKViews` are contained within view controllers who's logic changes. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Okay, still, in SK you have one view and one view controller. If you need to change some logic depending on the scene, this logic should go in the scene subclass. Your view controller should merely delegate any event to the scene as needed to allow the scene to handle it. In SK the scenes are kind-of like the view controllers for a given scene.

Comment: Hmmmm. My project uses a UICollectionView to display grid-squares (music notes) that SpriteKit nodes interact with. Is this implementation not advisable? How would I implement a UICollectionView in SpriteKit then?

Comment: well, for one you can't "add" sprites to the collection view as they aren't views themselves

Comment: Yes indeed. It is definitely the case that UIKit and SpriteKit don't play nice. I guess I'd like to conclude by asking two questions: 1. If you are building something in SpriteKit, is your entire codebase SpriteKit-based? 2. My original question: How should I push a view controller in a non-animated way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was with non-retina and retina assets. Make sure you have @2x and regular image assets, then you'll be fine.